# ReferenceError: answer is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

if (user_question!=false){
rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);
  rl.close();
});
console.log(calling_a_function(answer))
}
```

How can i fix the ReferenceError: answer is not defined
 error.

Comment: By defining `answer`?

Comment: i just started learning, how can i define it?

Comment: Your last call to `console.log` tries to use a variable (`answer`) which doesn't exist in that context.

Comment: @user9103606 You should start with picking a book on JS.

Comment: It does , this line should get the answer rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer)  the user gives so i can use it bellow

Comment: `answer` is defined only for your anonimous function

Comment: Ok any suggestion on how to fix my code so i can actually take the users answer and use it as intended.

Comment: Move the `calling_a_function` line inside the callback.

Answer (score 0):

The `answer` variable is a parameter to a function:

```
(answer) => {
    // TODO: Log the answer in a database
    console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);
    rl.close();
}
```

So it only *exists* within that function.  But then you try to use it later, *outside* of the function:

```
(answer) => {
    // TODO: Log the answer in a database
    console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);
    rl.close();
}
//...
console.log(calling_a_function(answer));
```

You can't use that variable there because it doesn't exist there.  The scope of the variable is only the block of code (function in this case) where it's defined.

Aside from the scope, you logically also can't use it there because it looks like it's the result of an asynchronous operation.  Which means the value you're looking for won't have been set at that time anyway.  (You can't log a value to the console *before* the user has entered that value.)

Instead, move that logging operation to *within* the function:

```
(answer) => {
    // TODO: Log the answer in a database
    console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);
    rl.close();
    console.log(calling_a_function(answer));
}
```

Comment: can you suggest an easier way to take a user's input and be able to use it later on in my code

Comment: @user9103606: "Easier" in what way?  Currently you prompt for user input, get a response, and have code which handles that response.  What are you trying to achieve besides this?

Comment: Basically i fixed my code as you asked and when i run it, for some reason rl.question('what do u think of node.js ', function(answer).. is not being triggered, so i'm not getting an error message but i'm not being asked that question, and i have put session.send just above it in the if to make sure it's getting in the if, which it was.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a that function based on the answer the user has given you need to do that *within the scope of the callback* provided by the `question` method.

```
rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
  console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);
  r1.close();
  calling_a_function(answer);
});
```

Comment: That's a  bit complicated, can you suggest an easier way to take a user's input and be able to use it later on in my code